# Jenkins unable to read the files from a folder for JAVA File I/O

Tags: java, jenkins, nullpointerexception, jenkins-pipeline

In the following method a part of my code is reading a list of xml files from a folder and returns the list of files. Everything works fine in eclipse but while buillding the same on jenkins, it is failing?

code snippet:

```
public List<File> getFileList(String dir) {

        File folder = new File(dir);

        List<File> FileList = new ArrayList<File>();

        for (File file : folder.listFiles()) {

            if (file.exists()
                    && file.getName().substring(file.getName().lastIndexOf('.') + 1).contentEquals("xml")) {

                FileList .add(file);
            }
        }
        return xmlFileList;
    }
```

> error on jenkins build, it says null pointer exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.akash.anand.executive.MyClass$FileReader.getFileList(MyClass.java:218)
```

Comment: Which line up there is line 218 from the error?

Comment: Don't use the abbreviated for-loop on `listFiles()`. It can return null, and it has done so in this case. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score 0):

The `dir` variable you are passing to getFileList, does it point to a hardcoded path? This might not be available in the Jenkins system.

Since it is a `NullPointerException` i presume the line `File folder = new File(dir);` is throwing null pointer as value of `dir` is itself null.
print the `dir` variable prior to initialising `folder` object.